# jquery mobile add click event on nested button

Tags: uibutton, jquery-mobile, mouseclick-event

i have a nested buttons and im trying to add click events on it but it seems not to be working.

this is my object

```
<div id="ui-50">
<div class="ui-rpc" data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" >
    <input type="button" id="rpc-bor" value="<<" />
    <input type="button" id="rpc-back"  value="<" />
    <span style="margin:3px"></span>
    <input type="text" id="rpc-jump" value=""  />
    <input type="button" id="rpc-next" value=">" />
    <input type="button" id="rpc-eor" value=">>" />
    <span style="margin:20px"></span>
    <label id="rpc-current" >0</label>
    <label id="rpc-separator" >/</label>
    <label id="rpc-total" >0</label>
    <span style="margin:20px"></span>
    <label id="rpc-rpp" >0</label>
</div>
</div>
```

im trying to add click event on id="rpc-eor" button using

```
$("#ui-50 .ui-rpc #rpc-eor").click(function(){
    alert("yay!");
});
```

but the event wont fire. what is the matter? please help! thanks in advance

Comment: Which version of jQuery.mobile are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am seeing the `console.log` output as expected in this demo I ran in Chrome, using [jQuery.mobile 1.0b1](http://jquerymobile.com/download/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
  <head> 
     <title>Page Title</title> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0b1/jquery.mobile-1.0b1.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0b1/jquery.mobile-1.0b1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("div:jqmData(role='page')").live('pageshow',function(){
            $("#ui-50 .ui-rpc #rpc-eor").click(function(){
                console.log("yay!");
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
</head> 
<body>
<div data-role="page" id="home">
    <div data-role="header">
       <h1>Header</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <div id="ui-50">
            <div class="ui-rpc" data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" >
                <input type="button" id="rpc-bor" value="<<" />
                <input type="button" id="rpc-back"  value="<" />
                <span style="margin:3px"></span>
                <input type="text" id="rpc-jump" value=""  />
                <input type="button" id="rpc-next" value=">" />
                <input type="button" id="rpc-eor" value=">>" />
                <span style="margin:20px"></span>
                <label id="rpc-current" >0</label>
                <label id="rpc-separator" >/</label>
                <label id="rpc-total" >0</label>
                <span style="margin:20px"></span>
                <label id="rpc-rpp" >0</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Note: [there is no `document.ready()` for jQuery.mobile](http://markdalgleish.com/2011/04/document-ready-for-jquery-mobile/) so if you have wrapped the jQuery in *just* `document.ready()` then it might be causing your problem. It is better to bind on `$("div:jqmData(role='page')").live('pageshow',...);` to guarantee that the page is ready. That said, in this simple case it still works without the `.live` bind.

Answer (score 0):

Try only the id

```
$("#rpc-eor").click(function(){
    alert("yay!");
});
```

Comment: thanks. yes this should also work. i discovered my problem. I used alpha version of the css, when i changed it to beta version my code works! thanks for your support